# Is it possible to construct a system of equations for which the set of solutions is a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

I may just be overthinking it at this point, but I've struggled to come up with one system of equations that results in a plane. Is it possible? I can't seem to convince myself of a disproof that its possible yet and so I believe it is possible just due to intuition.

Comment: what kind of an equation do you want? take $0 = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ or $z = 0$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of n equations, 3 variables (unless a plane's definition applies to more variables? I guess that would be the same but I don't think it does)

Comment: Then mm-aops's second example works: $0x+0y+z=0$. There are $n$ equations in $3$ variables; here $n=1$.

Comment: I mean I guess that works then? The realisation that I spent all of this time with 3+ equations for nothing makes me feel dumb now